# java.lang.NullPointerException using Spring Bean with constructor injection

Tags: dependency-injection, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a NullPointerException in a class which I can't explain why. It uses Spring Framework version 2.5.6, it's a Spring bean. The line of code at 70 is

```
userPreferenceService = (UserPreferenceService) MyAppContext.getApplicationContext().getBean("userPreferenceService");
```

The application context has this

```
    <bean id="userPreferenceService" class="com.service.PreferenceServiceImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="displayFieldsDAO" />
    <constructor-arg ref="displayPrefDAO" />
    <constructor-arg ref="savedQueryDAO" />
    <constructor-arg ref="userDAO" />
</bean>
```

I can't figure out where the null pointer is coming from. Is it because it can't access the ApplicationContext? If not, this is the only spring bean that it can't access, the many other beans are fine.

Or maybe it's one of the constructor-args that's returning null?

```html
2015-06-15 16:01:39,184 ERROR (com.ui.util.CreateUserSSOFilter:74) - 
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ui.util.CreateUserSSOFilter.init(CreateUserSSOFilter.java
:70)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:
343)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.ja
va:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.loadFilter(FilterManager.java:96)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.preloadFilters(FilterManager.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletCon
text.java:1872)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3
154)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.ja
va:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:
52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.jav
a:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.j
ava:200)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInv
oker.java:247)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.ja
va:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:
52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.jav
a:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.ja
va:27)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:
52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:59)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChe
cker.java:161)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerI
nvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(Abst
ractOperation.java:569)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeplo
yment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(Acti
vateOperation.java:116)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(Abstra
ctOperation.java:323)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(D
eploymentManager.java:844)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(D
eploymentManager.java:1253)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentM
anager.java:440)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(Deploym
entServiceDispatcher.java:163)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDelivere
r.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDelivere
r.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDelivere
r$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManage
rImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```